# Rails 4: Ajax button for follow users doesn't respond

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4.1

So i have a rails 4 app and i tried to implement a Follow/Unfollow system between users, following the chapter 11 of the [rails tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users)

But When I click to the follow button - nothing happens it's like the AJAX method is not working.

**app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb**

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

And to call the Follow/Unfollow Ajax method I'm using this:

**app/views/relationships/create.js.erb**

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>")
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>')
```

**app/views/relationships/destroy.js.erb**

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>")
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>')
```

I have the correct id set in my follow form,

```
<% unless @user == current_user %>
  <div id="follow_form">
  <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
    <%= render 'unfollow' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'follow' %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The error from the javascript console is:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/relationships 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js?body=1:9667
send jquery.js?body=1:9667
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js?body=1:9212
$.rails.rails.ajax jquery_ujs.js?body=1:81
$.rails.rails.handleRemote jquery_ujs.js?body=1:157
(anonymous function) jquery_ujs.js?body=1:364
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js?body=1:4625
elemData.handle jquery.js?body=1:4293
```

Any ideas of where this error come from ? Thanks

Comment: Can you post the ajax js?

Comment: Hmm @meves, sorry what do you mean by AJAX js? it's in the question under destroy.js.erb and create.js.erb

Comment: Do you see anything in the server log when you press the buttons?

Comment: Also check the Javascript console of your browser for any errors

Comment: I edited my question with the error I have from the javascript console

Answer (score 0):

Are these code listings direct copies from your code, or hand typed?

I think I was having the same issue.  **In my case, I finally traced it down to the create.js.erb file.**

**app/views/relationships/create.js.erb**

```
$( "#follow_form" ).html( "<%= escape_javascript( render( 'users/unfollow' ) ) %>" )
$( "#followers" ).html( "<%= @users.followers.count %>" )
```

The problem was the second line call to `@users.followers`, which should be `@user.followers`

HTH